# Creating a Custom Sorter for CollectionView.CustomSort in Powershell

Tags: powershell, sorting, icomparer

I am kinda' new to Powershell and have searched the ends of the earth for a solution, but I can't seem to find anything. I hope it's still doable.

I am trying to sort a `CollectionView` by date that's in string format. In my custom sorter, I  want to convert the date strings (M/dd/yyyy) into Date objects and have the `Comparer` sort it by date. My `CollectionView` is filled like this:

```sh
$stuff = [System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[System.Object]](ImportClixml -Path $path)
$view = [System.Windows.Data.CollectionView]([System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource]::GetDefaultView($stuff))
```

The `XML` data is filled with `Properties` that are `String` and `Boolean` values. the Date value I am trying to sort is a `String`. The `CollectionView` is the bound to a `DataGrid` like so: `$myDataGrid.ItemsSource = $myCollectionView`
Can I just make a function that sorts and just point to it somehow?

```sh
function customSorter{ #Do Stuff }
$myCollectionView.CustomSort = customSorter
```

The `CustomSort` property takes in a `System.Collections.IComparer` object. I'm not sure how to approach this. I would prefer to just keep it all in powershell 4 and not import C# code or something like that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What contains "#Do Stuff"? It would be interesting to know what kind of process is done to fill the collectionView in order to help you

Comment: @ManuP Hi, I have edited my post with the way I fill my CollectionView. That #DoStuff was the function I was going to make in order to sort, if that is how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can format your string dates into a datetime object

For example, `yyyy-MM-dd` format will be easy to sort.

If you want to convert your string dates you can use :

```
$timeinfo = '6/06/2017'
$template = 'M/dd/yyyy'
$newDate = Get-Date([DateTime]::ParseExact($timeinfo, $template, $null)) -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Result is : `2017-06-06`

Comment: Thank you. I am going to use that solution for now, but do you by any chance know how to make a custom sorter? I wanted to call the sorter whenever an event was called and I wanted to sort the collection view.

Comment: Do you have an example of the results you want? If you simply want to display an array of custom objects just use `$stuff = Import-CliXML -Path $Path` and sort `$stuff` by date (=properties?) when needed

Comment: The CollectionView is the ItemsSource of a DataGrid and I wanted to sort the Date column when it was clicked. I have the event function set up, just didn't know how to set `$myCollectionView.CustomSort = ?` With your solution, would I be doing that with the CollectionView?

Comment: I presume you use a Datagrid in a WPF form, so sort can just be done by clicking on the header of the column, no need to use a "customsorter". `$stuff = Import-CliXML -Path $Path` and `$datagrid1.ItemsSource = $stuff` and use headers to sort.

Comment: If sort by clicking on headers does not work, set Datagrid with `AutoGenerateColumns = False` and set 2 columns in Datagrid (one for properties and the other for the boolean values) with appropriate databinding

Comment: It's not sorting correctly right now because it's sorting it as a `String`, but I guess i can use your solution reformat it correctly and then reformat is again when I export it. How would I use your solution in conjunction with the `Import-Clixml`? And you said I can just sort `$stuff` by date. I tried sorting by date like this `$view.SortDescriptions(New-Object System.ComponentModel.SortDescription "Date", $direction), but it just sorts it as a `String`.

Comment: I resorted to using a "customsorter" because of a few reasons: I have to keep the date format "m/dd/yyyy" for exporting, I would have to loop through over 2k items to change the format for both importing and exporting, I want to use the built-in property.

Comment: To keep date format but casting as a datetime object : `$newDate = Get-Date([DateTime]::ParseExact($timeinfo, $template, $null)) -Format "M/dd/yyyy"`

Comment: `$stuff = Import-CliXML -Path $Path | Select-Object @{n="Date";e={Get-Date([DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Date, "M/dd/yyyy", $null)) -Format "M/dd/yyyy"}},Value`

Comment: `$datagrid1.ItemsSource = $stuff`

Comment: I let you change `$_.Date` and `Value` in `Select-Object` because I don't know the name of your properties

Comment: When I do the `Select-Object` on the `Import-Clixml` and click on the column header, it still sorts it as a `String` so months that start with a `1` like `10`, `11`, or `12` are sorted as `1`, not as the whole number. Maybe I'll just give up and just reorder the whole `CollectionView` with a sort algorithm.

Comment: Why not use a correct formatted date like `(yyyy-MM-dd)` in the datagrid and when you need to use a date in a function, you convert it like `(M/dd/yyyy)`.

Comment: I would have to convert each date when I `Import-Clixml` into a `DateTime` object for it to sort correctly because it doesn't sort correctly when it's a `String`. How would I do that along with other properties like `Title`, `Description`, and `Date`?

Comment: Try `$stuff = Import-CliXML -Path $Path | Select-Object Title,Description,@{n="Date";e={Get-Date([DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Date, "M/dd/yyyy", $null)) -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"}}`

Comment: That works, but when I export it, it adds a bunch of weird values. Is there a way to add a temporary `DateTime` property to the object that doesn't get exported?

Comment: What kind of weird values?

Comment: It added a `MS DateTime` property object with a bunch of properties. I guess I'll just have to try converting it back to a `String` when I export...

Comment: is there a way to dynamically add the other non-date properties during the `Import-Clixml`?

Comment: Is it possible to get an example of the Import-CliXML output?

Comment: no, i'm sorry, i meant that it displays fine in the `DataGrid`, but when I export it to xml, it displays with a bunch of weird values.

Comment: When you export, use `Export-CliXML | Select-Object Title,Description,@{n="Date";e={Get-Date($_.Date) -Format "M/dd/yyyy"}}`

Comment: what do you mean Import-CliXML output? you mean the xml file contents?

Comment: it has to be converted back to a string on `Export`

Comment: `Export-CliXML | Select-Object Title,Description,@{n="Date";e={(Get-Date($_.Date) -Format "M/dd/yyyy").ToString()}}`

Comment: is there a way to dynamically include everything like `Title`, `Description`, and 'Date' instead of actually typing every property out? Like mayebe a `Foreach` that goes through all the properties and when it's the `Date` then it converts it?

Comment: You can use `Export-CliXML -Path "xxx" | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty xxx` where `xxx` are all propeties you don't want to be exported but by this way, you can't redefine the Date property as we did before